# Undefined value of checbox in angular-js

Tags: html, angularjs

HTML Part:

```
<label>Do you want to check this?  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkModel" >
      </label><br/>
```

Controller Part:

```
  $http.post("InsertParticipant.jsp?comments1=" + $scope.comment +  "&checked_value=" + $scope.checkModel + "&request_id=" +id).
                                         then(function(response){
                                                           if(response.data.match("SUCCESS")){

                                        alert("Entry has been added");

                                }
                                else{
                                        alert("Sorry something went wrong Try filling it again");

                                }
```

It is coming undefined for the checkbox value.Can someone help me how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add values for your checkModel variable, like so

`$scope.checkModel = {
       value1 : true,
       value2 : 'YES'
     };`

See the angular.js documentation with examples here: [angular-input[checkbox]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

Answer (score 1):

You should add **value** to input.

In AngularJS you can set:

- ngTrueValue - The value to which the expression should be set when selected.
- ngFalseValue - The value to which the expression should be set when not selected.

[Check input[checkbox] documentation.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)